# Check under debug mode for ARM semihosting

Tags: debugging, arm

I'm study cortex-m4 for semihost and use stm32f429-discovery board.
I have a trouble with that semihost can not work when board is standalone(without in debug mode),
So, I hope to use judge debug status before printf(), like

```
if ((CoreDebug->DHCSR & CoreDebug_DHCSR_C_DEBUGEN_Msk) \
        ==CoreDebug_DHCSR_C_DEBUGEN_Msk) {
    printf("THIS IS SEMIHOST\n");
}
```

In normal situation, it will be like my expect, in debug mode, I can see semihiost log, in standalone, nothing pending. But in one situation, when I just burn the code into flash (using openocd or texane stlink with stlink hardware in linux). The first time it run, the bit of debug mode`(CoreDebug->DHCSR & CoreDebug_DHCSR_C_DEBUGEN_Msk)` keep being 1. I thought it should not be in debug mode, even I press reset hardware button on the board, it still keep 1, and the program will pending in printf().

After I plug out the power and then plug again, the debug mode bit will back to 0,  and it work correctly now, Is this trouble can be solved? or I use wrong openocd command? Thanks.

openocd command I use:

```
openocd -f interface/stlink-v2.cfg -f target/stm32f4x_stlink.cfg \
-c "init" \ 
-c "reset init" \
-c "flash write_image erase XXX.bin 0x8000000" \
-c "reset run" \
-c "shutdown"
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug register state is persistent across a normal CPU reset (otherwise you would be unable to set breakpoints). Power cycling the board will reset the state (obviously).

You ought to be able to clear DHCR.DEBUGEN thought the DAP if you need to script this 'flash and release' sequence.